# Setting cellForRowAt for static tableViewCellsd

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sigabrt

As soon as I implement this and transfer data from another view, whenever I go to settings menu, it throws a SIGABRT error. Could you tell me what to do?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = stackTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pEditCell", for: indexPath)
    self.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "Image-10")
    self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
    let profileVC = ProfileViewController()
    self.usernameLabel.text = profileVC.Username.text
    self.statusLabel.text = profileVC.statu.text
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error in console? Possibilities: You want a VC with a Xib, and `ProfileViewController()` is not calling it, so you may have a "found nil while unwrapping an optional value" error. Another potential issue: "profileVC.Username.text", `userNameLabel` may not be loaded yet (won't work). And why do you need to call a VC there?

Comment: If your table view is static do not use the table view data source methods. You can access the UI elements directly with IBOutlets

Comment: @Larme I want to transfer data between the views.

Comment: @vadian I am not using data source methods, I am accessing them right through my ViewController file.

Comment: `let profileVC = ProfileViewController()` That's creating a NEW object, not the one that you think calling.

Comment: `cellForRowAt` is clearly a data source method.

Comment: @Larme how do I get data from another view then?

Comment: @vadian Ah, okay, see what you mean :)

Comment: use struct or singleton to store the value in profile view controller and show in static tableview

Comment: It depends. What's the hierarchy/where/when is used `ProfileViewController` and your cell?

Comment: @Larme there's no segue between them, that's why I ask